# split background into 3 divs flippable

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a background into my html/css website but I also want to split this background into 3 divs who can flip when the cursor is hover.

So I guess the best to do could be to make 3 divs side by side (the total size of my screen) then to apply 3 backgrounds to these 3 divs but each of them are a different part of my background image.

Is anyone here can show me how to do that with a snippet please ?

Comment: here is what I actually done : https://codepen.io/glupidon/pen/JjOJxpo

Comment: That is a simple solution for him.

Comment: @AwatITWork that's actually where I'm stuck, this is not a solution

Comment: @peter,
then, I will write down a simple solution for you.

Comment: thanks, can't wait to see that

Comment: background images are not available .

Comment: what's your solution problem? that's look good.

Comment: I just made some fix but I'm not satisfied yet ... i want using only one image as a background and split it into 3 div. So when my cursor is hover one of these 3 div only 1/3 of the background is fliping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Flipping with backside content

```css
/* css reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}


/* ---- */


/* flexbox to place partitions beside each other */

.image-canvas {
  display: flex;
}


/* making each partition of 1/3rd width */

.image-section {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}


/* image container to keep a part of the image */

.image-section .image {
  transition: transform 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* image to span the screen width */

.image-section .image img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}


/* content container to span the partition width */

.image-section .content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  /* optional centering */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* flip effect to image */

.image-section:hover .image {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* reverse flip effect to content */

.image-section:hover .content {
  transform: rotate(0);
}


/* showing only a portion of the image on each partition by dragging to the desired position */

.image-section.one img {
  left: calc(-1 * ((100vw / 3)) * 0);
}

.image-section.two img {
  left: calc(-1 * ((100vw / 3)) * 1);
}

.image-section.three img {
  left: calc(-1 * ((100vw / 3)) * 2);
  /*   right: 0; */
}
```

```html
<section class="image-canvas">
  <div class="image-section one">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Part one">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Part one
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-section two">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Part two">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Part two
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-section three">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Part three">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Part three
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I have used the following series of steps to achieve your result:

1. Take a flex container.
2. Take a partition `div` with `flex-basis: calc(100% / 3)` inside of the container and place two elements for image and content.
3. Rotate the content section to `180deg` and `backface-visibility:hidden` to hide it when the image is showing.
4. Apply flip effect to the image on hover, and reverse flip effect to content on the same hover.

---

## Flipping without backside content

```css
/* css reset */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}


/* ---- */

.image-canvas {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-section {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s;
  /*   backface-visibility: hidden; */
}

.image-section img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.image-section:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.image-section.one img {
  left: calc(-1 * ((100vw / 3)) * 0);
}

.image-section.two img {
  left: calc(-1 * ((100vw / 3)) * 1);
}

.image-section.three img {
  left: calc(-1 * ((100vw / 3)) * 2);
  /* right: 0; */
}
```

```html
<section class="image-canvas">
  <div class="image-section one">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Partition 1">
  </div>
  <div class="image-section two">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Partition 2">
  </div>
  <div class="image-section three">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Partition 3">
  </div>
</section>
```

---

I have used the following series of steps to achieve your result:

1. Take a container and set it to full width of the screen.
2. Place three `div`s with one-third width of the total width inside of the container.
3. Make the container `flex` to place the partitions beside each other.
4. Place an `img` with the same `src` inside each of the partitions spanning the width of the screen.
5. Pull the second image by `100vw / 3` from the left.
6. Pull the third image by `(100vw / 3) * 2` from left (or `0` from right).
7. Apply flip effect using `transform: rotateY(180deg)` and animation effect using `transition: transform 1s` to the images.

---

References:

- [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)
- [Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)
- [Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)
- [Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc())
- [Backface visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility)

Comment: That's exactly what I want !! Thanks a lot for that mate.

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to help!

Comment: do you have any idea how to make a front and back div when the picture flip ?

Comment: Take a container (let's all it card) with 2 things in it: The front image and the back content. Apply flipping effect of image and `backface-visibility: hidden` to the card. rotate the back content of the card to 180% to make it 0% on flip. Place the content element behind the image using `z-index`. And I think you should be good to go. (I will try to incorporate this in the answer if I get enough time today, though; but that's pretty much it!)

Comment: That's what I try,  but I will follow your instruction

Comment: @Xodarap, I have added the code for backside content. I seems that it was not as easy as I told you. I had to flip the content beforehand and then reverse-flip it on hover.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. I will use it. This technique is easier than all of what I already try to do

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this question using an SVG file while you are using to use the same image but a separate part of it. Please let me know if you are looking for something like this, also, upvote my answer,
I have some difficulties while uploading this code sample, still not what I wanted, but I'll let you what I have created for ya, I used the same image side by side, both of them complete the one image. try to re-create this sample below and let me know.

I forget to tell you, in the viewbox you can easily change that.

```css
.flip-card {
                background-color: transparent;
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                perspective: 1000px;
            }

            .flip-card-inner {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                transition: transform 0.6s;
                transform-style: preserve-3d;
                box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            }

            .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }

            .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
            }

            .flip-card-front {
                background-color: #bbb;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
            }

            .flip-card-back {
                background-color: #2980b9;
                color: white;
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5">

        <h2>Let me know if you still need help Peter</h2>        
        
        <div class="row row-cols-3">
            <div class="flip-card" id="card1">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">

                        <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                             width="300.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="-150 0 400.000000 400.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                            <g transform="translate(0.000000,400.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
                                <path d="M0 2000 l0 -2000 2000 0 2000 0 0 2000 0 2000 -2000 0 -2000 0 0
                                -2000z m620 -100 l0 -320 -25 0 -25 0 0 320 0 320 25 0 25 0 0 -320z m2700 0
                                l0 -320 -25 0 -25 0 0 295 0 296 -84 -71 c-47 -38 -87 -70 -90 -70 -3 0 -6 10
                                -5 23 0 29 170 167 205 167 l24 0 0 -320z m-2292 123 c13 -8 28 -25 34 -39
                                l11 -24 32 34 c60 65 162 67 209 3 19 -26 21 -44 24 -223 3 -188 3 -194 -17
                                -194 -19 0 -20 8 -23 191 l-3 191 -28 24 c-35 30 -85 31 -121 3 -50 -40 -56
                                -64 -56 -244 0 -155 -1 -165 -19 -165 -17 0 -19 12 -23 178 -5 217 -18 251
                                -98 251 -41 1 -70 -20 -99 -69 -19 -32 -21 -51 -21 -197 0 -156 -1 -163 -20
                                -163 -19 0 -20 7 -20 230 0 223 1 230 20 230 16 0 20 -7 20 -37 l0 -38 23 28
                                c41 51 119 65 175 30z m660 16 c30 -6 59 -20 73 -35 23 -25 24 -31 27 -225 3
                                -175 1 -199 -12 -199 -12 0 -16 10 -16 40 0 22 -2 40 -4 40 -2 0 -20 -16 -40
                                -35 -81 -76 -209 -68 -254 16 -8 14 -11 46 -9 78 3 47 9 59 40 87 40 37 79 49
                                185 59 l72 7 0 34 c0 18 -5 44 -11 58 -24 51 -126 60 -246 22 -19 -6 -23 -4
                                -23 13 0 24 42 38 157 50 7 0 34 -4 61 -10z m422 0 c28 -6 64 -22 80 -36 l30
                                -25 0 31 c0 25 4 31 21 31 20 0 21 -4 17 -104 -3 -117 -15 -144 -79 -181 -38
                                -22 -159 -27 -195 -7 -25 14 -44 -1 -44 -34 0 -36 26 -47 130 -55 153 -12 200
                                -45 200 -140 0 -35 -6 -48 -38 -79 -48 -49 -103 -64 -202 -57 -96 7 -140 22
                                -140 49 0 15 4 18 18 13 119 -51 260 -39 306 27 19 26 21 71 5 100 -15 28 -69
                                48 -128 48 -111 0 -191 34 -191 82 0 11 7 32 15 48 14 27 14 32 -5 62 -37 62
                                -18 157 41 201 22 16 63 30 101 36 4 1 30 -4 58 -10z m507 -10 c52 -19 82 -76
                                99 -186 l6 -43 -172 0 -173 0 7 -42 c9 -57 33 -104 62 -123 47 -30 145 -35
                                223 -10 15 5 21 2 21 -10 0 -36 -129 -55 -213 -31 -63 18 -106 61 -126 125
                                -14 48 -14 154 0 204 29 105 152 158 266 116z"/>
                                <path d="M1571 1816 c-120 -43 -103 -206 22 -206 87 0 157 75 157 166 l0 54
                                -72 -1 c-40 0 -88 -6 -107 -13z"/>
                                <path d="M1972 1976 c-34 -32 -37 -38 -37 -91 0 -51 3 -60 31 -84 78 -70 241
                                    -31 245 58 5 105 -40 151 -146 151 -49 0 -59 -4 -93 -34z"/>
                                <path d="M2453 1990 c-37 -22 -60 -61 -69 -119 l-7 -41 147 0 146 0 0 35 c0
                                    48 -22 97 -55 123 -37 29 -117 30 -162 2z"/>
                            </g>
                        </svg>

                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h1>Div One</h1>
                        <span>Place some text here peter....</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" id="card2">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">

                        <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                             width="300.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="250 0 400.000000 400.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                            <g transform="translate(0.000000,400.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
                                <path d="M0 2000 l0 -2000 2000 0 2000 0 0 2000 0 2000 -2000 0 -2000 0 0
                                -2000z m620 -100 l0 -320 -25 0 -25 0 0 320 0 320 25 0 25 0 0 -320z m2700 0
                                l0 -320 -25 0 -25 0 0 295 0 296 -84 -71 c-47 -38 -87 -70 -90 -70 -3 0 -6 10
                                -5 23 0 29 170 167 205 167 l24 0 0 -320z m-2292 123 c13 -8 28 -25 34 -39
                                l11 -24 32 34 c60 65 162 67 209 3 19 -26 21 -44 24 -223 3 -188 3 -194 -17
                                -194 -19 0 -20 8 -23 191 l-3 191 -28 24 c-35 30 -85 31 -121 3 -50 -40 -56
                                -64 -56 -244 0 -155 -1 -165 -19 -165 -17 0 -19 12 -23 178 -5 217 -18 251
                                -98 251 -41 1 -70 -20 -99 -69 -19 -32 -21 -51 -21 -197 0 -156 -1 -163 -20
                                -163 -19 0 -20 7 -20 230 0 223 1 230 20 230 16 0 20 -7 20 -37 l0 -38 23 28
                                c41 51 119 65 175 30z m660 16 c30 -6 59 -20 73 -35 23 -25 24 -31 27 -225 3
                                -175 1 -199 -12 -199 -12 0 -16 10 -16 40 0 22 -2 40 -4 40 -2 0 -20 -16 -40
                                -35 -81 -76 -209 -68 -254 16 -8 14 -11 46 -9 78 3 47 9 59 40 87 40 37 79 49
                                185 59 l72 7 0 34 c0 18 -5 44 -11 58 -24 51 -126 60 -246 22 -19 -6 -23 -4
                                -23 13 0 24 42 38 157 50 7 0 34 -4 61 -10z m422 0 c28 -6 64 -22 80 -36 l30
                                -25 0 31 c0 25 4 31 21 31 20 0 21 -4 17 -104 -3 -117 -15 -144 -79 -181 -38
                                -22 -159 -27 -195 -7 -25 14 -44 -1 -44 -34 0 -36 26 -47 130 -55 153 -12 200
                                -45 200 -140 0 -35 -6 -48 -38 -79 -48 -49 -103 -64 -202 -57 -96 7 -140 22
                                -140 49 0 15 4 18 18 13 119 -51 260 -39 306 27 19 26 21 71 5 100 -15 28 -69
                                48 -128 48 -111 0 -191 34 -191 82 0 11 7 32 15 48 14 27 14 32 -5 62 -37 62
                                -18 157 41 201 22 16 63 30 101 36 4 1 30 -4 58 -10z m507 -10 c52 -19 82 -76
                                99 -186 l6 -43 -172 0 -173 0 7 -42 c9 -57 33 -104 62 -123 47 -30 145 -35
                                223 -10 15 5 21 2 21 -10 0 -36 -129 -55 -213 -31 -63 18 -106 61 -126 125
                                -14 48 -14 154 0 204 29 105 152 158 266 116z"/>
                                <path d="M1571 1816 c-120 -43 -103 -206 22 -206 87 0 157 75 157 166 l0 54
                                -72 -1 c-40 0 -88 -6 -107 -13z"/>
                                <path d="M1972 1976 c-34 -32 -37 -38 -37 -91 0 -51 3 -60 31 -84 78 -70 241
                                    -31 245 58 5 105 -40 151 -146 151 -49 0 -59 -4 -93 -34z"/>
                                <path d="M2453 1990 c-37 -22 -60 -61 -69 -119 l-7 -41 147 0 146 0 0 35 c0
                                    48 -22 97 -55 123 -37 29 -117 30 -162 2z"/>
                            </g>
                        </svg>

                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <h1>Div Two</h1>
                        <span>Place some text here peter....</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have used a dummy image here at dummyimage.com more help about SVG at [www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns) and a useful website to view paths at mapsvg.com
[image]

Comment: well thanks Peter for your work, I will try to use it to fix my issue, I let you know soon.